# Where does the PLCP sublayer layer actually reside?

Tags: wireless-networking

Does the OS perform PLCP preamble and header addition to packets or is this done automatically by NIC firmware? I.e. Are PHY_SAP functions performed by the NIC and called by the OS MAC layer?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLCP is handled by the NIC implementation, not the OS. Whether it's done in NIC hardware, NIC firmware / microcode running on the NIC, or perhaps in the NIC's driver running on the host, it is a per-NIC implementation detail. It has to be the NIC because the preamble changes based on the data rate / modulation selected, and the data rate decision is usually a NIC implementation detail too (NICs automatically vary data rates / modulations from one packet transmission to the next, in order to maximize reliability and performance despite the ever-varying RF environment conditions).